# excel, vlookup, error message, we found a problem with this formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a vlookup. Please see below. I am trying to do the vlookup in cell vlookup37 below. I have never received this error message before. I am very used to doing vlookups and have never had this issue. This excel file is large and has a filter on. Please see below. Thanks for your help.

```
=vlookup(A38, Sheet2!A2:A125,1,false)
```

Error Message

> We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more info on common formula problems.

[image]

Comment: cannot replicate issue

Comment: Please see my below response

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, but I don't know why I needed to do this. I followed the directions on the popup error message and I followed the wizard. It produced the below syntax which worked.

```
=VLOOKUP($A38|Sheet3!$A$2:$AZ$587|9|FALSE)
```

Comment: then your local settings require the `|` instead of the `,` as the delimiter.  It has nothing to do with Excel.

Comment: Thanks so much! I needed to change that to produce a pipe delimited file before. I need to undo that now.